# algorithm for two phase totally ordered multicast

Tags: operating-system, cloud, system, distributed-computing, distributed-system

I am trying to understand the **two-phase totally ordered multicast**. This distributed system method is used to ensure that all receivers in a multicast group receive messages in *the same order*. Note: I was able to understand the totally ordered multicast approach that uses a central sequencer but I can't understand the two-phase approach that **doesn't use a central sequencer**. Some online material[1][2] describes it but I fail to visualize it and would appreciate if someone can explain the steps involved and possibly a simple example as well.

[1]https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/course/15-446/applications/ln/lecture9.html
[2]http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~ghosh/11-20-03.pdf

Thanks